# What is the default executor of ListenableFuture in Java?

Tags: java, asynchronous, future

Here is my code below:

```
@Component
public PaymentClass ...

    private BigDecimal addAllAmount(List<String> list) {//here is the list
        List<ListenableFuture<Response>> responseFutures = new ArrayList<>();

        for(String str:list){
            responseFutures.add(payment.query(getQueryRequest(str)));//external soa service
        }

        List<BigDecimal> listOfAmount = new ArrayList<>();
        for(ListenableFuture<Response> future : responseFutures){
            Response response = (Response)future.get();
            listOfAmount.add(response.getAmount());
        }
        return listOfAmount.stream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
    }
    ....
}
```

The method 'addAllAmount' wants to sum up the payment amount, for the performance I use ListenableFuture to make the external SOA service called 'payment.query' asynchronous. My question is: I do not assign any other thread pool, how many threads will create? Same as the size of 'list'?

Comment: How do you create those Future objects? What is `payment.query()` method and `getQueryRequest(str)`?

Comment: @michalk getQueryRequest(str) method just create a Request Object ,payment.query() method returns ListenableFuture<Response>.It was created in a normal way

Comment: What does "normal" way mean? show the code of `payment.query()` method or at least the part that creates ListenableFutures.